# Cでランタイムエラーが出ますが、原因が分かりません

Tags: c

[AtCoderの ABC240-B](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc240/tasks/abc240_b) を解く問題をCで書こうとしたのが下記のコードです。

問題は「n個の正整数からなる配列aの中に、何種類の整数が現れるか。」というもので、これを解くために、aの最大値+1 の要素を持つ配列numsを作り、aを順番に見ていってnums[a[i]]を加算しています。(本問の場合0か1にしてもいいのですが、各要素が何個ずつあるか知りたい場合にも使えるように整数の種類ごとにその数を数えています。)

Paiza.io でコードを実行しており、小規模なデータならばこれで動くのですが、例えば以下のデータだと、25行目の `(*(nums+num)+=1;)` で `Runtime error(Exit status:137(Kill signal))` というエラーが出ます。

なお、このコードは、特にデータが下記の例のようなものの場合にはメモリの無駄が多く、いいコードではないことは承知していますが、とりあえずこれを完成させたいです。

**作成したコード:**

```
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax);
int readint(char *s);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N1 20
#define N 2e9
int main(void){
    char* s1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N1);
    fgets(s1,N1,stdin);
    int n=readint(s1);
    free(s1);
    char* s2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
    fgets(s2,N,stdin);
    int * a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    input_iarray(s2,a,n,N);
    free(s2);
    int max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (*(a+i)>max)max=*(a+i);
    }
    int * nums=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(max+1));
    for(int i=0;i<=max;i++)*(nums+i)=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int num=*(a+i);
        *(nums+num)+=1;
    }
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if (*(nums+i))ans++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",ans);
    return 0;
}
int readint(char *s){
    int i=0,ret=0;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
//        printf("%d\n",*(s+i));
        ret*=10;
        ret+=*(s+i)-48;
        i+=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
void input_iarray(char* s,int* a,int n,int imax){
    int aidx=0,i=0; 
    while(*(s+i)!=0 && i<imax){
        if (*(s+i)<48 || *(s+i)>57){i++;}
        else{
            int bidx=i;
            while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
                i++;
            }
            int t=0;
            for(int j=bidx;j<i;j++){
                t*=10;
                t+=*(s+j)-48;
            }
        *(a+aidx++)=t;
        }
    }
    if (aidx!=n)printf("n!=aidx aidx=%d\n",aidx);
}
```

**試したデータ:**

```
1000
1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000
```

Comment: Paiza.ioは[利用ガイド](https://paiza.io/help)にもある通り「実行時間のタイムリミット」と「メモリ制限」があります。そのため、メモリ効率や実行時間に課題を抱えている場合には不適切な環境になりえます（このコードが該当するかはさておき）。質問文への直接的な回答ではありませんが、ローカルでの実行確認を検討したほうが良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```c
    int * nums=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(max+1));
```

`max`の最大値は10^9(問題の制約より)なので、`sizeof(int)`が4だとすると、上記コードで最大約4GBのメモリを確保しようとします。しかし、paiza.IOだとメモリ制限512MB(質問へのコメントのリンク先より)なので、全然足りません。メモリが十分にある環境で実行するか、メモリの使用量を減らすようにコードを書き換えましょう。実際、私のローカル環境で実行したところ、特にエラーもなく動作しました(結果は0で間違っていましたが)。

なお、`malloc`は失敗すると`NULL`を返すので、戻り値を使う前に必ず`NULL`でないことを確認するようにしましょう。今回もおそらく上記コードで`NULL`が返って、それをそのまま使おうとしてRuntime errorとなっています。